# What is the difference between "number" and "Number" in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

In TypeScript, there are two distinct "number" types. The first one is called lowercase `number`, and the second is uppercase `Number`. If you try printing `number`, there is compiler error:

```js
console.log(number); //-> error TS2693: 'number' only refers to a type
```

On the other hand, printing `Number` will give the standard function description:

```js
console.log(Number); //-> [Function: Number]
```

This is unsurprising as `Number` is just a built-in JS constructor documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). However, it is unclear, what `number` is supposed to be.

Judging by the error message, it seems that `number` isn't actually a discrete value(?!) like `Number`. But despite this, it is used in variable and function declarations as if it is a value, like:

```js
var two: number = 2;
function sqr(x: number) { return x; }
```

On the other hand, user-defined types like classes appear to be discrete values (as they also print the standard function description). And, to further complicate matters, `Number` can be used in annotations similar to `number`:

```js
var two: Number = 2;
```

There is similar cases with `string` and `String`, `any` and `Object`, etc.

So, my question is: **What are `number`, `string`, etc in TypeScript, and how are they different then built-in constructors?**

Comment: They are **types**, being permitted only in type annotations. Just like user-defined `interface`s. The types for primitive values are builtin, though, you cannot define such your own.

Comment: Btw, `const number = 2` is valid Typescript :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`number` is only a TypeScript thing - it's a primitive type referring to, well, a number.

> But, judging by the error message, it seems that number isn't actually a discrete value like Number.

Indeed - it's a type, so it doesn't exist in emitted code.

> a discrete value like Number. On the other hand, user-defined types like classes appear to be discrete values (as they also print the standard function description).

Yes. Classes, of which Number is one, are special. They do two things, somewhat unintuitively:

- They create a JavaScript class (usable in emitted code)
- They also create an interface for the class (only used by TypeScript)

If you use `Number` in a place where a **type** is expected, TypeScript will not complain, because `Number` is an interface.

If you use `Number` in a place where a **value** (something that exists in emitted code) is expected, TypeScript will not complain, because `Number` is also a global constructor.

In other words, the two `Number`s below refer to *completely different things*:

```
// refer to the TypeScript Number interface
let foo: Number;

// refer to the JavaScript global.Number constructor
const someNum = Number(someString);
```

Using Number in TypeScript is very odd, since it'd, strictly, speaking, refer to a number created via `new`:

```
const theNum = new Number(6);
```

Which there's almost never a reason to do. Use a plain primitive number instead, without an object wrapper.

```
const theNum = 6;
// theNum is typed as `number`
```

Answer (score 2):

From https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#the-primitives-string-number-and-boolean:

> JavaScript has three very commonly used
> [primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive):
> `string`, `number`, and `boolean`. Each has a corresponding type in
> TypeScript. As you might expect, these are the same names you’d see if
> you used the JavaScript typeof operator on a value of those types:
>
> - `string` represents string values like `"Hello, world"`
> - `number` is for numbers like `42`. JavaScript does not have a special runtime value for integers, so there’s no equivalent to `int`
>   or `float` - everything is simply `number`
> - `boolean` is for the two values `true` and `false`
>
> > The type names `String`, `Number`, and `Boolean` (starting with capital letters) are legal, but refer to some special built-in types
> > that will very rarely appear in your code. Always use `string`,
> > `number`, or `boolean` for types.

(There are also [typs for `null` and `undefined`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#null-and-undefined))